# How to display a 32-bit DIV result stored in DX:AX

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I wrote this code to display a current value after some calculations. But the program gives wrong output when it should gave decimal 10 result it gives 13107 result and i cant find the reason why. Before this label what I did was basically getting inputs from the user and storing those values at si register.

```
islem: 

  MOV AX,[SI+14]
  MOV BX,[SI+10]
  MOV CX,[SI+2]
  
  SUB AX,BX
  SUB AX,CX
  
  MOV BX,[SI+8]
  
  MOV [SI+16],AX
  
  MOV DX,00H
  MOV AX,[SI+16]
  DIV BX
  
  
  
  MOV [SI+18],OFFSET IE
  
  MOV [SI+18],AX
  MOV [SI+20],DX
  
  CALL NEWLINE
  
  mov dx, offset Ie_msg
  mov ah,9
  int 21h
  
  MOV AX,[SI+18]
  MOV DX,[SI+20]
  

  
    mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    push    bx             ;Sentinel
a: mov     cx,ax          ;Temporarily store LowDividend in CX
    mov     ax,dx          ;First divide the HighDividend
    xor     dx,dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx             ; -> AX is HighQuotient, Remainder is re-used
    xchg    ax,cx          ;Temporarily move it to CX restoring LowDividend
    div     bx             ; -> AX is LowQuotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx             ;(1) Save remainder for now
    mov     dx,cx          ;Build true 32-bit quotient in DX:AX
    or      cx,ax          ;Is the true 32-bit quotient zero?
    jnz     a             ;No, use as next dividend
    pop     dx             ;(1a) First pop (Is digit for sure)
b: add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     dx             ;(1b) All remaining pops
    cmp     dx,bx          ;Was it the sentinel?
    jb      b             ;Not yet
  



ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AX,[SI+18]
> MOV DX,[SI+20]
> ```

The result of your calculation came from a division (`div bx`). **The quotient is held in the `AX` register only**. The `DX` register contains the remainder from the division.

Just load `AX` with `mov ax, [si+18]` and then zero `DX` with `xor dx, dx`.
Hereafter you can run my conversion code...

Comment: He  wants to display a 32-bit number.

Comment: @prl No he doesn't. The calculation yields 16 bits. He's only asking about `DX:AX` because I previously linked him to an answer of mine that displays 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Sir I did what you reccomended but instead of getting the correct answer which is 10 , I got 6 which is the result stored in the quotient only. but I need to show the correct answer which is  stored in the dx:ax together 02:06 how can I change the code to give the correct output?

Comment: @BengisuAdsız How can the correct answer be 10 if `DX=2` and `AX=6`? That would produce `2 * 65536 + 6` which is 131078. You need to tell me what input numbers you're using at the top of your current posted program.

Comment: I am sorry sir i noticed that i made a calculation error in the start i changed it and now it gives the correct result as 10. thank you for your time and help. I am a she btw :)

Comment: @BengisuAdsız Happy to see that it helped you. (Sorry for the he/she thing)